# Method Not Found : Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DpiHelperLogicalToDeviceUnits

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I need to use ADO.NET Entity Model Object in my project but when I select to add the item from Visual Studio 2013 Template dialog, I instead encounter the error below.

> Method Not Found : Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DpiHelperLogicalToDeviceUnits

Does anyone know what I need to do to get rid of this?

I am on a Windows 7 machine, with Visual Studio 2013 and current SDKS installed

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the version of the designer included in this CTP that will cause the error to appear when trying to use the EF Tools.

Fix is here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/08/18/visual-studio-14-ctp-3-and-entity-framework.aspx